# How do I get the number of rows affected by a BULK INSERT on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get the number of rows affected by a BULK INSERT on SQL Server (2008 if that matters)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried examining `@@ROWCOUNT` ?

(Note: you need to set a variable = @@ROWCOUNT before executing any other statement, otherwise its value will be reset)

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT should work fine but *please* do think about maximum number of rows you are going to update on some day. If it is going to be more than 2 billion then use RowCount_Big() else it is going to be wrong on that *some* day.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful if any triggers fire as a result of your BULK INSERT, as this may affect your result.